# How to go through a loop and create a new object with each iteration Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, object, eval

I saw several variations of this question but did not really find a solid answer.

So I have an array of URLS. I want to loop through that array and for each individual URL, I would create an instance of class WebPages.

So if array URLS has 5 urls in it, then I would create 5 objects of WebPages. I tried to use eval() to do this but quickly learned that the instances made by eval have a very local scope and I cannot use those WebPage objects after.

```
string_to_eval = @urls.map{|x| "webpage#{urls.index(x)} = WebPage.new('#   {x}')"}.join(';')
puts string_to_eval
eval(string_to_eval)
```

String_to_eval prints out:

```
webpage0 = WebPage.new('http://www.google.com');
webpage1 = WebPage.new('http://www.yahoo.com');
webpage2 = WebPage.new('http://www.amazon.com');
webpage3 = WebPage.new('http://www.ebay.com')
```

How else can I make an object with each iteration of the loop in Ruby? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5):

Why not just this?

```
webpages = @urls.map { |url| WebPage.new(url) }
```

It is generally a bad idea to have `webpage0`, `webpage1`... when you can have `webpages[0]`, `webpages[1]`... (Also, the array way does not require the Evil of `eval`.)

Answer (score 2):

In this situation I would forgo unique variable names and instead simply leave the resulting objects in an array. In that case the code would look like this:

```
>> @urls.map{|url| WebPage.new(url)}
=> [WebPage('http://www.google.com'), WebPage('http://www.yahoo.com'), WebPage('http://www.amazon.com'), WebPage('http://www.ebay.com') ]
```